# Как получить данные, полученные в запросе Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

хотел сделать небольшое приложения с использованием запроса.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello world'


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processing():
    return request.form['text']
```

Сделал запрос и моя программа вывела:

```
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка?

Я делал вот такой запрос:

```
from requests import post
a = post('http://site.pythonanywhere.com', {'name': 'Oleg'})
```

Comment: Покажите, какой запрос делали и как

Comment: И как вообще запускаете этот код

Comment: @andreymal через pythonanywhere

Comment: Не уверен, но проблема может крыться в том, что pythonanywhere не позволяет обращаться к сайтам, которые не входят в белый список: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/ . Второе, приведите код темплейта html или ту часть темплейта, в которой есть форма с post запросом.

Comment: Еще проблема, как мне кажется, кроется в том, что `request.form['text']` должен выдать информацию из поля `text` - лично я не вижу template странички с этой формой, соответственно, в ней может крыться ошибка, от банального отсутствия этой формы, до ошибки построения ajax запроса в коде JavaScript.

Comment: Задплоил данный код, проблема в `return request.form['text']` (точнее, в `request.form['text']` ) - если заменить этот код на `return "blablabla"` , то ошибки не будет и сервер вернет ответ со статусом 200.

Comment: @ViktorIlyenko Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задплоил данный код, проблема в `return request.form['text']` (точнее, в `request.form['text']` ) - если заменить этот код на `return "blablabla"`, то ошибки не будет и сервер вернет ответ со статусом 200.

Соответственно, ищите ошибку в коде страницы, из которой должны быть получены данные.